# Angular builds fails only on github action

Tags: angular, unit-testing, github-actions, karma-jasmine

I have some angular tests, they all passes on my local machine. The build is fine and the tests too.

```bash
npm run build -- --configuration production
```

```
> project.net@0.0.0 build
> ng build --configuration production

Locale data for 'fr-FR' cannot be found. Using locale data for 'fr'.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files           | Names              |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.40b9d18cea9debef.js      | main               |   1.04 MB |               225.81 kB
styles.39e0e34266a8723e.css   | styles             | 396.52 kB |                29.27 kB
scripts.2366f6834ae39e44.js   | scripts            | 377.25 kB |               120.49 kB
polyfills.c14262a5744a7a9b.js | polyfills          |  34.29 kB |                11.07 kB
runtime.c12b062db9f7e4ff.js   | runtime            |   2.86 kB |                 1.35 kB

                              | Initial Total      |   1.83 MB |               387.98 kB

Lazy Chunk Files              | Names              |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
900.f4e9f6038b59958d.js       | Admin-admin-module | 783.02 kB |               140.25 kB
640.4608da492a45fac2.js       | Admin-admin-module | 341.92 kB |                57.86 kB

Build at: 2022-12-16T14:06:14.821Z - Hash: 0efd680ede9213b8 - Time: 23625ms
```

But when it's running on github action I have errors, and I can't find why. I also don't know how to reproduce the error on my local machine.

Here is the github action file, which is for the test:

```yaml
name: Tests
on:
  push:

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Write env
        run: >
          touch ./src/environments/environment.ts &&
          echo "export const environment = {" > ./src/environments/environment.ts &&
          echo "production: false," >> ./src/environments/environment.ts &&
          echo "domain_auth: 'http://localhost:8850'," >> ./src/environments/environment.ts &&
          echo "domain_api: 'http://localhost:8851'" >> ./src/environments/environment.ts &&
          echo "}" >> ./src/environments/environment.ts
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Cache node modules
        id: cache-nodemodules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          # caching node_modules
          path: node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-build-
            ${{ runner.os }}-
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: steps.cache-nodemodules.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          npm install
      - name: Build
        run: |
          npm run build -- --configuration production
      - name: Test
        run: |
          npm run test:prod
```

This action fail on the `Build` step, here is the error:

```
Run npm run build -- --configuration production

> project@0.0.0 build
> ng build --configuration production

Locale data for 'fr-FR' cannot be found. Using locale data for 'fr'.
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Warning: /home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/Services/session.service.ts depends on 'moment'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



./src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:32:0-67 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './inputs/select/select.component' in '/home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/commons'

./src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:34:0-98 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './cadre/cadre-comparaison/cadre-comparaison.component' in '/home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/commons'

./src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:35:0-101 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Button/bordure-fond-blanc/bordure-fond-blanc.component' in '/home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/commons'

./src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:36:0-95 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './rating/basic-rating-bar/basic-rating-bar.component' in '/home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/commons'

./src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:37:0-94 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './chevron/chevron-basique/chevron-basique.component' in '/home/runner/work/project-front/project-front/src/app/commons'

Error: src/app/Admin/admin.module.ts:154:5 - error NG6002: 'CommonsModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

154     CommonsModule,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/commons/commons.module.ts:100:14
    100 export class CommonsModule {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
```

The error seems to be on my CommonsModule, but it's working fine on my local machine:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {ClipboardComponent} from './components/clipboard/clipboard.component';
import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import {TooltipModule} from 'primeng/tooltip';
import {ColorPickerComponent} from './components/inputs/color-picker/color-picker.component';
import {InputComponent} from './components/inputs/input/input.component';
import {InputTextModule} from 'primeng/inputtext';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {PasswordModule} from 'primeng/password';
import {InputMaskModule} from 'primeng/inputmask';
import {InputTextareaModule} from 'primeng/inputtextarea';
import {SwitchComponent} from './components/inputs/switch/switch.component';
import {InputSwitchModule} from 'primeng/inputswitch';
import {BandeauPromoComponent} from './components/header/bandeau-promo/bandeau-promo.component';
import {SurnavbarComponent} from './components/surnavbar/surnavbar.component';
import {SurnavbarRatingComponent} from './components/surnavbar/surnavbar-rating/surnavbar-rating.component';
import {SurnavbarButtonComponent} from './components/surnavbar/surnavbar-button/surnavbar-button.component';
import { CheckboxInputComponent } from './inputs/checkbox-input/checkbox-input.component';
import { CheckboxModule } from 'primeng/checkbox';
import { ReturnButtonComponent } from './components/return-button/return-button.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {PdfViewerComponent} from './components/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component';
import {NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule} from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
import {SkeletonModule} from 'primeng/skeleton';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';
import {SaveFormDirective} from '../Directives/save-form.directive';
import { ModalFormComponent } from './components/modal-form/modal-form.component';
import { EncartComponent } from './components/encart/encart.component';
import {SafeHtmlPipe} from '../Pipes/safe-html.pipe';
import {SelectComponent} from './inputs/select/select.component';
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
import {CadreComparaisonComponent} from './cadre/cadre-comparaison/cadre-comparaison.component';

import {BordureFondBlancComponent} from './Button/bordure-fond-blanc/bordure-fond-blanc.component';
import {BasicRatingBarComponent} from './rating/basic-rating-bar/basic-rating-bar.component';
import {ChevronBasiqueComponent} from './chevron/chevron-basique/chevron-basique.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ClipboardComponent,
    ColorPickerComponent,
    InputComponent,
    SwitchComponent,
    BandeauPromoComponent,
    SurnavbarComponent,
    SurnavbarRatingComponent,
    SurnavbarButtonComponent,
    CheckboxInputComponent,
    ReturnButtonComponent,
    SaveFormDirective,
    ModalFormComponent,
    EncartComponent,
    SafeHtmlPipe,
    PdfViewerComponent,
    SelectComponent,
    CadreComparaisonComponent,
    BordureFondBlancComponent,
    BasicRatingBarComponent,
    ChevronBasiqueComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ClipboardComponent,
    ColorPickerComponent,
    InputComponent,
    SwitchComponent,
    BandeauPromoComponent,
    SurnavbarComponent,
    CheckboxInputComponent,
    ReturnButtonComponent,
    SelectComponent,
    SaveFormDirective,
    EncartComponent,
    PdfViewerComponent,
    ClipboardComponent,
    CadreComparaisonComponent,
    BordureFondBlancComponent,
    BasicRatingBarComponent,
    ChevronBasiqueComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    TooltipModule,
    InputTextModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PasswordModule,
    InputMaskModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    FormsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    RouterModule,
    DropdownModule,
    InputSwitchModule,
    SkeletonModule,
    ButtonModule,
    NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule,
  ]
})
export class CommonsModule {
}
```

I tried to delete my loca `node_modules` then re-install it and re run the build but still no error on my local computer. I also deleted the `node_modules` cache on github action and re-runned the action, still the same error.

What could cause this error, but only on github action ?

Comment: you can try to replicate the error by running it in docker container, or just remove node_modules to make sure you're not relying on a module that you;ve got installed and it's not on github (missing in package json)

Comment: Th commons module that fails is a local module inside the project. How can I run the process inside docker ? Is there a tool that allow me to run github action locally ?

Comment: What do you mean by removing node_modules ? You mean on my local machine ? Or are you saying that it could be a cache problem from github action, that cached a previous version of node_modules  ?

Comment: yes, remove it locally and npm install again, then build again

Comment: I deleted my `node_modules`, runned `npm install` then the build and still no problem locally

Comment: try to find circular dependencies: `npx madge --circular src/app`, make sure node version is the same,

Comment: I ran the command and got `✔ No circular dependency found!`

Comment: maybe show entire CommonsModule  class? :)

Comment: the entire code is in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the errors, but I am not sure why.

On the github pull request I could see two folder "Commons" and "commons". But locally I only have one directory:

[image][image]

I think the problem happened because we were two developers working on similar parts, we both created a commons module, but one with a capital "C". When we merged our work we kept only one directory. But I don't know why github kept the location of some components inside the other directory.

**To fix this :**

1. I renamed the commons module by adding one letter "commonst"
2. I renamed it back to "commons"
3. Git detected changes, I added them and commited.
4. Then everything is working fine